# Call DispatcherServlet's protected render method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, reflection

I have created a jar with JSTL tags. In my class I have a `modelAndview` object. I want to render the `modelAndView` object using Spring's `DispatcherServlet's` `protected` `render` method.
Currently, what I have done is that I have `extended` `DispatcherServlet` Class and added a static `renderView()` method that internally calls the protected `render()` method.

```
public class DispatcherServlet extends org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet {

private static DispatcherServlet servlet;

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    servlet = this;
    super.init(config);
}

public static void renderView(ModelAndView mv, HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    servlet.render(mv, request, response);
}
```

}

I want to avoid extending DispatcherServlet because I am actually asking my clients to define my custom DispatcherServlet in their `web.xml`.
If somehow I can get DispatcherServlet object and make a call to protected render() method then my problem might get solved.
Any good suggestions.

Comment: You *can* extend the `DispatcherServlet` from Spring and still ask your clients to define your custom `DispatcherServlet` in their `web.xml`. Why not do that? In fact, you're already extending it... I might be missing the exact point of your question though.

Comment: I don't want my client to use my `DispatcherServlet` because they might already be using some other custom `DispatcherServlet`.